# clear fragment history in drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application, I have 5 fragments and the requirement is that on any given fragment, if back button is pressed, it should exit out of the application. In other words the fragments does not have any order and are independent. SO pressing the back button on any fragment will actually close the app itself.

In some fragments, I am opening other fragments using this code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

track nextFrag= new track();
login.this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, nextFrag, null)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

However the history is still maintained, What can I do to clear the history on start of any fragment.

EDIT:
Tried this and the application does exit on pressing back, however I can still see a glimpse of previous activity and it throws some nasty exceptions.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: .addToBackStack(null) is adding fragment into history. just remove this line.

Comment: "I can still see a glimpse of previous activity"  Are you looking to clear the Fragment history or the Activity history?